# RAID Controller Link Speed

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, sas

I was wondering what sequential speed should I expect from a RAID controller that has 1 x MiniSAS 6Gbps port.

In the product details -> Data Transfer Rates: Up to 6Gb/s per port

Does this MiniSAS port has 4 x 6Gbps link or just 1 x 6Gbps link? Should I expect 750MBps sequential speed max or 4 x 750MBps speed max?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your *disk* setup (number of disks, capacity, rotational speed) and RAID level.

As for theoretical limits, a 4-lane SAS connector, like an [SFF-8087](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg), provides 4 x 6Gbps links for devices operating at 6Gbps. That is 24Gbps total. There are also 3Gbps devices out there, so link speed is adjusted down accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Generally miniSAS ports have 4 independent 6Gbps links inside, they can be negotiated as one 24Gbps link, but you need an active backplane for that and controller able to do that.

So, you can be quite sure about the 4 x 750MBps speed.